# How would I change this code to a different format? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

The code below is the code that I have written:

```
function singer(artist) {
    var songs = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < music.length;i++ ){
        if(music[i].artist.indexOf(artist) > -1) {
            songs.push(music[i].name);
        }
    }
    return songs;
}
```

The code that I want to look similar to the function singer(artist) code is this:

```
const genreCount = () => {
    const genres =  music.reduce((result, cur) => {
        cur.genres.forEach(g => {
            if (result.hasOwnProperty(g)) {
                result[g] += 1;
            }
            else
                result[g] = 1;
        });

        return result;
    }, {});
    return genres;
}
```

I am unfamiliar with this type of format in Javascript, how would I change it so that const genreCount will look like function singer(artist).

Comment: Is there a specific purpose of changing the format? If you want to learn about the syntax see any JS tutorial, e.g. [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Comment: Keep in mind the readability of both the formats

Comment: `const singer=artist=>music.filter(({artist:a})=>a.includes(artist)).map(({name:n})=>n);`

Comment: I am still fairly new to Javascript and I'm unsure of how to really understand the second format.

Comment: Use [babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBA5gUzAJwQYRAVzLAvDACgEoZcA-GAbwCgYZRJZEUEJSYBbTCAS2ADpUAE0zAEBAqgiYANlAA09TMhLkqtOkuT9mU_gDMQyAKIBDYAAsCcUhRqbNPfYSmyo_C6YgB5AO5gABWQQAAcEZCgAT2siIg0HOlc5AG04AF0YAGp8AEYAbnjNBBkIBEKHJKhUjNyChwBfIgLC1ChlMBhKuph6xUpG7tb2-CQpAvqgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&version=7.7.3&externalPlugins=) to transpile

Answer (score 0):

this style is called functional programming

```
const singer = artist => music.filter(m => artist.indexOf(m.artist) > -1).map(m => m.name)
```

here is a good interactive tutorial if you are interested
[Functional Programming in Javascript](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/)

UPDATE:
oops, sorry for misunderstanding your questions
here is genreCount rewritten with for-loop:

```
function genreCount(){
  const genres = {};
  for(var i=0; i<music.length; i++){
    var g = music[i]
    if (genres.hasOwnProperty(g)) {
      genres[g] += 1;
    }
    else{
      genres[g] = 1;
    }
  }
  return genres;
}
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question that I asked. I want the genreCount() function to look similar to the code of function singer(artist). The reason why I want that is because I don't really understand the Javascript format for genreCount().

Answer (score 0):

This is what you will get if you want to change that function:

```
function genreCount() {
    const genres =  music.reduce(function(result, cur) {
        cur.genres.forEach(function(g) {
            if (result.hasOwnProperty(g)) {
                result[g] += 1;
            }
            else
                result[g] = 1;
        });

        return result;
    }, {});
    return genres;
}
```

or (if you want to assign that fucntion to a `const` anyway):

```
const genreCount = function() {
    const genres =  music.reduce(function(result, cur) {
        cur.genres.forEach(function(g) {
            if (result.hasOwnProperty(g)) {
                result[g] += 1;
            }
            else
                result[g] = 1;
        });

        return result;
    }, {});
    return genres;
}
```

You just should replace `arrow functins` with the `regular function expressions`. But I don't know why do you need that.